# Plugin download from live site

Tags: plugin, extensions, download

Joomla 3.4

Is it possible to download (already installed) plugins from a live website?

My scenario is that I downloaded a free plugin a while back, extracted it somewhere on my local pc and can't find it again! However I do have the same plugin installed on one of my other live hosted websites, so is it possible for me to 'download' it from Website A, re-zip, and upload it to Website B? If so, how?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

The most important thing to do is carefully read through the plugin XML file, paying special attention to the `<files>` and `<languages>`.

I would suggest creating a folder on your desktop, and in there, put all the plugin files that are defined in the `<files>`. Of course, use subdirectories if any have been defined.

As for the languages, download them and place them in the folder you have created on your desktop. if you see `folder=""` attribute used on the `<languages>` tag, create a sub-directory and place the language files in there instead.

Once done, zip up the folder and install it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Lodder. Are the plugins stored at `/administrator/plugins` or somewhere else? The plugin in question is part of RSForms `com_rsform`

Comment: Plugins are location in `ROOT/plugins/...` ;)

Comment: Perfect! Congratulations on the 10k rep btw ;) Well deserved!