# How to transfer a module between sites

Tags: module

My problem is clear, I have a module on a sample Joomla project and I want to transfer is as it is to another Joomla site of mine. How might that be possible? I have searched the database and found the entries about the modules, but I have seen that there might be mutliple entries for each mod_* folder. Which is the way to go?

Comment: This is the process for a plugin however it may help http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10840/plugin-download-from-live-site

Comment: Worked more or less that way

Comment: And put an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy and paste the `mod_* folder` to get the files and scripts.

You can find the row about the module on `#__extensions` to get the configuration params.

In  `#__modules` and `#__modules_menu` you can find how it is showed on site.  But you can reconfigure by **Joomla Administrator** and after copy and paste the params if necessary

Answer (score 1):

Your site has many module instances in #__modules. One for each created module in Module Manager. For instance, if you have 10 Custom Html modules, you will find 10 records for mod_custom.

You only have to insert in your target site the instance that your are looking for.

Also, notice that you are not copying menu assignment (#__modules_menu). You have to manually assign the module in the target site.