# Component Download (from a live site)

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, extensions, migration

I asked a [similar question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10840/plugin-download-from-live-site) a while back regarding downloading a *plugin* from a live site - however this question is concerning a *component*, perhaps the process similar?

Quick recap - I downloaded a (purchased) .zip gallery component a while back, and installed this on a live site, all working fine. I would now like to install this **same** component on another (different) website, but I can't find the original .zip file that I paid for.

Is it possible for me to download/ftp the complete component from Website A, and re-upload to Website B? If so, how? I have full ftp access to both websites.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with a component, but it will take a little longer as there are more directories and files.

---

Create a folder on your desktop (e.g "**gallery**"), then copy the XML file from:

> ROOT/administrator/components/com_component/component_name.xml

into your newly created folder.

---

### Step 1:

Open the XML file and inside you will see something like:

```
<files folder="site">
```

and

```
<files folder="admin">
```

So inside your **gallery** folder, create 2 sub-directories called "**site**" and "**admin**".

---

### Step 2:

Now to copy the main component files.

Go to `ROOT/administrator/component/com_component` and copy the entire contents (apart from the XML you copied before), into your "**admin**" directory

The go to `ROOT/component/com_component` and copy the entire contents, into your "**site**" directory

---

### Step 3:

Look again in your XML file and you will also see a reference to some language files, for example:

```
<languages>
    <language tag="en-GB">site/languages/en-GB/en-GB.com_component.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">site/languages/en-GB/en-GB.com_component.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

Looking at this example, you will now need make sure you have to following directory path created:

> gallery/site/languages/en-GB

Once done, copy the 2 language files (from your server):

```
ROOT/languages/en-GB/en-GB.com_component.ini
ROOT/languages/en-GB/en-GB.com_component.sys.ini
```

into the directory you create just a minute ago.

You will also need to repeat the same process for the admin language files, but of course ensuring they go in the "**admin**" directory instead.

---

Once all done, zip up the component and try installing it.

If there are any errors about missing files, have another look at the XML file and see if you've missed anything, such as media (CSS, JS etc)

Hope this helps

Comment: I know question is about downloading it from website A. It should also be mentioned that OP could just move files from A to B to same places and use Joomla! discover method. Then OP dosen't have to create zip.

Comment: @johnny_s you need to create these 2 folders  named as `admin and site` and place the files & folders in these folders respectively